# Stuck on low resolution with missing network

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, nvidia, display-resolution

This is a long and complex quest of issues which all seem to inter-relate. It starts with using my system as normal, and then installing and trying to run WoeUSB to create a Windows 10 boot disk to load another machine, but failing several times. After this, Gnome encounters an error and asks me to log out to correct it. I log out, but can never log back in, being stuck on a permanent purple screen. I hop over to TTY3 and reboot, and this is where the fun begins.

When my PC comes back online, I notice that the resolution is very low, and my second monitor is completely blank. The display settings show that the resolution is set for 1024x768, though it feels a lot lower than that. There are no other options for other resolutions, and my display isn't recognized. I open "Additional Drivers" to try and swap over to another driver, thinking this one has just encountered an issue, but when it opens I find all other drivers are greyed out and I'm unable to switch. I open a command prompt, run `apt update` and `apt upgrade` and reboot. However, this has not resolved the issue.

I go googling and find an article recommending to run `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-dkms-510`, which I do. I reboot hoping it will fix my problems. However things just got worse. Not only was everything still stuck at a low resolution with no second monitor, but now my network connectivity was gone. I couldn't ping the outside world, and I couldn't ping my router. `ip addr` just shows a loopback interface, and my wired ethernet connection is missing. I know it's not an issue with my router, because no other machine in my house is having this issue, and even when I boot onto a live CD on this machine it doesn't have the issue.

For context I am running Ubuntu 20.04, using an nvidia 610 graphics card, and am using the built-in network adapter of my Gigabyte B660M motherboard.

TL;DR: NVidia drivers broke and trying to fix them just made my network disappear

Comment: Because restoring my home directory and all my programs will take a day in and of itself. Plus I refuse to believe there's nothing that can be done to salvage this, only problem is that all my googling has lead to surface level answers which don't really work

Comment: You have at least three separate problems plus whatever additional problems were caused by trying things that didn't work. Well organized backups let you recover from any loss with as little down time as possible. Trying to sort through all of this mess will take more time and effort.  However if you really want to untangle this, we will need more information. We need to know exactly what you've done so far, include all commands/actions you've taken and the detailed results of each. The more "long and complex" the problem, the larger the burden to communicate it to others.

Comment: So far all the only thing I've changed that wasn't listed in the description above is that I booted into advanced startup a couple times and ran DPKG a couple times, which I did before losing network. And then after losing network I changed GRUB to no longer give a quiet start.

My main frustration has been I can't even find diagnosis tools to determine if it's an actual problem or if it's just a small thing that looks big and scary

Comment: I'm sure it would have been less time spent on the issue if anyone actually attempted to provide solutions or at least diagnostic tools instead of just throwing my hands up for me and telling me to reinstall, while acting like backups and restoration take no time whatsoever. I'm tired of seeing "if it was important you'd have already backed it up" as if nothing can happen before you get to finish a backup

Comment: If you're looking for a simple solution or magic pill to diagnose or repair widespread problems, that's what a reinstall does.  There's nothing else that will fix all your problems.  You yourself described the situation as *"a long and complex quest of issues"*.   I've explained to you the volume and types of information you will need to provide to continue to troubleshoot your current installation. Feel free to add that information as well as any other information requested by any other volunteer willing to go down this rabbit hole with you.